# Select one record for same OrderNumber

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this;

Id - Title - OrderNumber - CreatedOn

---

1  -  First  - 1       - 01.01.2015 
2  -  Second - 2       - 02.05.2015 
3  -  Third   - 2       - 03.08.2015 
4  -  Fourth   - 3       - 04.04.2015 
5  -  Fifth - 4       - 07.06.2015

I want to get the newest record for each OrderNumber. So, I don't want to get the second row for this example. Do you have any idea how can i do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ordernum order by createdon desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```